# Query MongoDb collection regarding an array of objects in a Go project

Tags: mongodb, go, slice

In a `Go` project I stored some data like this in a `MongoDb` Collection:

```
{
    _id:ObjectId("631f0752da589137a71687f6"),
    target: { roomId: '11' }
}

{
    _id:ObjectId("43150752da589137a71687f6"),
    target: { roomId: '12' }
}
.
.
.
```

I have a target array of objects and I want to check the database that if a `roomId` in database is equal to one of my array of objects values or not.

My target array of objects:

```
 userRooms:[{"roomId":"12"}, {"roomId":"13"}, {"roomId":"14"}]
```

I create a new array containing just room Id's like this:

```
var roomIds []string
for _, v := range RESPONSE.USERROOMS {
    roomIds = append(roomIds, v.ROOMID)
}
```

I do it like this:

```
bson.M{ "target": bson.M{"roomId":bson.M{"$in": roomIds }}}}}})
```

It doesn't work. it returns zero results.

Comment: I think you have to map `userRooms` to `[12, 13, 14]`

Comment: I create an array like you said. but still I get zero results. Its possible you to give me the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct a filter for a nested field, use the dot `.` to designate the field with its full "path":

```
bson.M{"target.roomId": bson.M{"$in": roomIds}}
```

Where `roomIds` should be the slice of IDs, e.g. of type `[]string` or `[]any`, but it should contain the room IDs as `string`s.